# Missing cursors in WPF

Tags: c#, user-interface, mouse-cursor

Windows Forms has the cursor types `Cursors.NoMoveHoriz`, `Cursors.NoMoveVert` and `Cursors.Default`.

These identifiers do not exist in WPF. Is there a way to obtain them anyway (without a reference to WinForms) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these Cursors just have different names in WPF.

- `Cursors.NoMoveHoriz` is `Cursors.ScrollWE`
- `Cursors.NoMoveVert` is `Cursors.ScrollNS`
- `Cursors.Default` is `Cursors.None`

At least that's what this .NET fx source code suggests:
https://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Vista_SP2/Dotnetfx_Vista_SP2/8@0@50727@4016/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/Orcas/QFE/wpf/src/WinFormsIntegration/System/Windows/Integration/Convert@cs/1/Convert@cs

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed. The correspondence is correct for the fist two (but None is just no cursor). The documentation is truly helpful: "ScrollWE: Gets a west/east scrolling Cursor." :-)

Comment: Lol, that right, confusing. Maybe the coder @MS liked sailing  ;)

Comment: As to `Cursors.Default` winforms, it's, I think, `Cursors.Arrow` in WPF...

Comment: Yep, the "Default" is arrow. Anyway "Arrow" also exists in WinForms, so the day Microsoft decides to change "Default" to something else, I'll be stuck. :) This development must have been assigned to an intern.